# All Icons Missing, Explorer Progress Bar Never Finishes, Libraries Gone

Tags: windows-7, windows

Since yesterday I've had three issues which all arose at the same time.

> Windows 7 x64, i7 2.8ghz 12GB DDR3

1. My libraries, favorites, drives are missing. Basically the entire sidebar is gone.
   [image]

   Yet, when I open a dialog, my libraries and drives are back to normal **only** for the dialog.

   I tried **Restore Default Libraries**. Tt works one time, but when I open libraries again I go back to the empty mess. Restarting the computer temporarily fixes the problem.
2. In the Explorer window that's showing libraries, when I navigate to a certain folder I get an unending progress bar (the kind that turns the address bar green).

   Yesterday when the problem started, I was saving a file to this folder. The program writing the file crashed during the write and I believe that's what caused the problem. I have sugarsync backing up that folder and when I restarted the computer sugarsync informed me that its database was corrupted, so I had to uninstall and reinstall the software.
3. Icons are missing. The **Rebuild Icon Cache** did not fix this.
   [image]

---

Restarting the computer temporarily fixes these problems, but when I open the directory with the initial write problem, everything stops working.

#### Edit:

I should note that I did a `chkdsk /f` and it repaired problems. I also did the thing that verifies then restores Windows files (can't remember the command now), which reported that everything was normal.

Comment: Have you tried a System Restore to a point before this started happening?

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear to me why this might have happened, but I would suggest running `chkdsk` to verify that your drive hasn't been corrupted. Some key files that store information about your libraries may have been affected and it may be causing Windows to fail when reading its library database (and could also have accounted for the failed write to the folder).

Comment: yes i ran this yesterday. the output is at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27269911/chkdsk.txt